# can gtk drawing area be styled with css?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I want to add a box-shadow to a gtk drawing area. As of now, I can't find a direct way to do so. The only way is to add the drawing area in a gtk box and then style the box accordingly. I would like to know if there is a css node for gtk drawing area.

Comment: As far as I know, no. It only has the default CSS node name: `widget`. And in GTK3 it did not actually ever apply any CSS set on it. I don't know whether in GTK4 it might do. Anyway, long story short - just put it in a Box or Frame or something and style the latter